# Convert FirebaseUser to a customized User class in a Stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to convert a `FirebaseUser` to a customized class by adding some extra fields in a Flutter project which is using `Firebase` as backend. Here is my code:

```
Stream<User> get user {
// return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_fromFirebaseUser);

final theUser = _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map((firebaseUser) {
  final result = Firestore.instance.collection("users")
    .document(firebaseUser.uid).snapshots().map((snapshot) { 
       return User(
         uid: user.uid,
         name: snapshot.data['name'],
         email: user.email,
         age: snapshot.data['age'],
         gender: snapshot.data['gender'] 
      );
   }
   return result;
  });
  return theUser;
}
```

The basic idea is I will get the data from users collection and populate the User model. But I got the following error message:

> The argument type 'Stream' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream'.

Need your advice on how to return a `Stream<User>` instead of `Stream<Stream<User>>`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you're using 2 streams: `_auth.onAuthStateChanged` and `Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).snapshots()`. You need to either combine it, or simply asynchronously get the user document from the collection instead of listening for a stream:

```dart
Stream<User> get user {
  return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.asyncMap((firebaseUser) async {
    final snapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .document(firebaseUser.uid)
        .get();
    return User(
        uid: firebaseUser.uid,
        name: snapshot.data['name'],
        email: firebaseUser.email,
        age: snapshot.data['age'],
        gender: snapshot.data['gender'] 
    );
  });
}
```

Note the using of `asyncMap` instead of `map` to allow asynchronous document fetch.

Comment: when the firestore user changes, how does this user stream update? since this stream only listens to auth changes and not firestore changes

Comment: @Karen if you want to listen for user updates as well, you need to combine these two streams